# Include only common merchants who made purchase (weekly level)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want if week 1 of 2022 14 merchants made purchase and in week 1 of 2023 10 made a purchase and in 2024 9 made purchase then we take lowest number and take only those merchants across week 1 of all years, in this case only 9 merchants who made purchase in 2024.

I want to take only common merchants for all 3 years who made purchase in specific week.

P.S. It needs to be same merchants on weekly level.

```
with cars as(
 SELECT DISTiNCT
         cs.buyer_id AS merchant_id,
         mm.country as merchant_country,
        CS.id AS car_id,
                FIRST_VALUE(m.created_on::date)
            OVER (PARTITION BY cs.buyer_id ORDER BY m.created_on ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS activation_date,
        DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', FIRST_VALUE(cs.b2b_deal_datetime::date)
            OVER (PARTITION BY ft.merchant_id ORDER BY cs.b2b_deal_datetime ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) AS purchase_month

        
    FROM WKDA.CAR_SALES AS CS
    LEFT JOIN wkda_merchant_financing.merchants AS m ON m.merchant_id = CS.BUYER_ID
    LEFT JOIN dwh_ba.fact_sold_cars_to_finance_eligible_merchants AS ft  ON CS.ID=FT.CAR_ID
    LEFT JOIN wkda.merchants AS mm ON cs.buyer_id=mm.ID
    where
cs.b2b_deal_datetime >= DATE_TRUNC('year', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 year') + INTERVAL '1 day'
AND cs.b2b_deal_datetime <= CURRENT_DATE
and buyer_id in
(select buyer_id 
FROM WKDA.CAR_SALES AS CS
LEFT JOIN wkda_merchant_financing.merchants AS m ON m.merchant_id = CS.BUYER_ID
  WHERE cs.b2b_deal_datetime >= '2022-01-01'::date
        AND cs.b2b_deal_datetime <= '2022-12-31'::date)

     

AND BUYER_ID IN
            
            (SELECT MERCHANT_ID FROM wkda_merchant_financing.financed_proforma
            )



)
   , purchases AS (SELECT merchant_id                                    AS merchant_id
                        , activation_date                                AS activation_date
                        , purchase_month                                 AS purchase_month
                        , DATE_DIFF('WEEK', DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', activation_date),
                                    DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', purchase_month)) AS nr_purchasing_week_after_activation
                        , COUNT(DISTINCT car_id)                         AS nr_cars
                      ,           merchant_country

                   FROM cars
                   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4,6)
   , merchants AS (SELECT DISTINCT merchant_id                                                                                              AS merchant_id
          ,  merchant_country

                                 , activation_date                                                                                          AS activation_date
                                 , nr_purchasing_week_after_activation                                                                    AS nr_purchasing_week_after_activation
                                 , COUNT(purchase_month)
                                   OVER (PARTITION BY merchant_id ORDER BY purchase_month ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS nr_of_purchasing_months
                                 ,nr_cars
                                 ,purchase_month
                  from purchases group by 1,2,3,4,purchase_month,nr_cars)

SELECT 
    'week' AS activation_time_scale,
    TO_CHAR(activation_date, 'YYYY_iw') AS activation_period,
    TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', purchase_month), 'IYYY') || '_' || 
    TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', purchase_month), 'IW') AS nr_purchasing_week_after_activation,
    nr_of_purchasing_months,
    nr_cars,
    merchant_id,
   merchant_country,

    COUNT(DISTINCT merchant_id) AS nr_merchants

  FROM merchants
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7;
```